# Using the moment generating function of uniform random variables to calculate the moments of the uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

The moment generating function of a uniform random variable over $[a, b]$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$ is:

$$ M(t) = \frac{e^{bt} - e^{at}}{t(b - a)} $$

Note that $M^{(1)}(t)$ will have a $t^2$ in the denominator, given the shape of the division rule for derivatives.

This means that $M^{(1)}(0)$ is not defined. So, how can one use it to calculate the expectation of the uniform distribution over $[a, b]$?

Comment: Note that it is not $M^{(n)}(0)$ that gives the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ moment of the distribution, but rather
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} M^{(n)}(t).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discontinuity at zero is [removable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html).
Take the derivative of $M$ and a limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ in the resulting expression.